# BackboneJS - Vertical menus in one view

Tags: backbone.js

I have multiple collections which i want to display as a vertical menu. So should I, for each menu, create a view and then load these views in one single-main view?

Here is what I want to achieve:

```
<div id="menu1">
  <span><h2>MENU 1</h2><span>
  <ul>
     <li>menu1_link1</li>
     <li>menu1_link2</li>
     <li>menu1_link3</li>
  <ul>
</div>

<div id="menu2">
  <span><h2>MENU 2</h2><span>
  <ul>
     <li>menu2_link1</li>
     <li>menu2_link2</li>
     <li>menu2_link3</li>
  <ul>
</div>

<div id="menu3">
  <span><h2>MENU 3</h2><span>
  <ul>
     <li>menu3_link1</li>
     <li>menu3_link2</li>
     <li>menu3_link3</li>
  <ul>
</div>
```

Should I create a model and a collection and a json file for each one of them?

Answer (score 0):

I would create 3 collections, 1 for each menu.
Every menu item will be model. So you can render titles like this this.model.get('title')

"So should I, for each menu, create a view and then load these views in one single-main view?"
It depends on your file structure, you can achieve this multiple ways, do you use requirejs?

Comment: yes, i'm using requirejs. you can check [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20600054/] if you like... :-)